# C# - Saving a DataGridView to file and loading

Tags: c#, datagridview

To start off, what I have is a simple Winforms app, with just a save and load button, and with a datagridview control to hold data. What I am looking to do is input some data into the control, hit the save button, and it save all the data to a file locally on the computer, and when I hit load, it loads the file and populates the control appropriately, keeping all rows, columns, and data the same as when saved.

Although it sounds fairly simple to me, I cant seem to figure a good way to save and load the data. Can I get a few pointers or examples to get myself started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bind the DataGridView to a DataTable, and use the DataTable
 `ReadXml()` and  `WriteXml()` methods to read and write the data to a file.

If you ever have multiple grids bound to multiple related tables, you can represent the schema with a DataSet and use the `ReadXml()` and  `WriteXml()` methods of DataSet to read and write the whole schema.

There is an example on the MSDN page for [DataTable.WriteXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx) that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested a simple way to save datagridview to a file :

```
//DataGridView dgv=...
string file= "c:\\mygrid.bin";
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.Create)))
{
    bw.Write(dgv.Columns.Count);
    bw.Write(dgv.Rows.Count);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvR in dgv.Rows)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; ++j)
       {
           object val=dgvR.Cells[j].Value;
           if (val == null)
           {
                bw.Write(false);
                bw.Write(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bw.Write(true);
                bw.Write(val.ToString());
             }
         }
    }
```

and for loading such a file into a datagridview:

```
//DataGridView dgv = ...
dgv.Rows.Clear();
string file="c:\\mygrid.bin";
using (BinaryReader bw = new BinaryReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)))
{
   int n=bw.ReadInt32();
   int m=bw.ReadInt32();
   for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
   {
         dgv.Rows.Add();
         for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
         {
               if (bw.ReadBoolean())
               {                                        
                     dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = bw.ReadString();                                        
               }
               else bw.ReadBoolean();
          }
     }
}
```

Consider that I have assumed that the datagridview control has fixed columns, in you specific situation you should add some codes to insert new columns or create a new gridview.