# "value of type datagridviewcell can not be converted to string" vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to take data from a DataGridView and save that data into a txt file so it can be loaded into the grid later.  Right now, it will save the file, but will not write to the file because of the error

"value of type datagridviewcell can not be converted to string" or

"An unhandled exception of type'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

I'm not sure what to do and I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    'SGD is my save file dialog box
    SGD.ShowDialog()
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(SGD.FileName)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In QAfield.Rows
            writer.WriteLine(row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn").ToString, row.Cells.Item("ScoreColumn"), row.Cells.Item("PassColumn"), row.Cells.Item("FailColumn"))

        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn").Value.ToString is probably what you're after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Saving a DataGridView to file and loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952161/c-sharp-saving-a-datagridview-to-file-and-loading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are not accessing the `value` to the `DataGridViewCell` rather the cell itself...

This return's the `DataGridViewCell`

```
 row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn")
```

When you add `ToString` you are trying to take this object and convert it to a string, that will not work and your exact error you are seeing.

```
  row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn").ToString
```

You need to access the [**value**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx) itself...

```
 row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn").Value.ToString()
```

Also on another note, if the `Value` is NULL it will throw an exception when adding `ToString` because you can't cast a NULL to an empty string. I would be checking this `value` before casting it to a string...

```
 If row.Cells.Item("AgentColumn").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then ....
```

Comment: Thank You So MUCH!

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help you