# Save and load dataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I've been looking everywhere but i couldn't find anything, I need want to know how to save and load data from a dataGridView with multiple columns and rows(not to a database but to my own PC). I would prefer to save to an .XML file but a .TXT work too. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You will get more constructive help if you tell us what framework you are using (Winforms? WPF? ASP.Net?) as well as anything that you have tried and why it didn't work.  Also, where is the initial data coming from?  Are you starting with a blank GridView and entering rows from scratch, or are you importing data from somewhere?

Comment: im coding in C# and im adding data from textboxes, hope this helps

Comment: All of the frameworks that I mentioned use C#, but the answer will be al little bit different for each.  For a question this broad, start with a Google search to see if you can find a tutorial, and then ask more specific questions (including samples of your code) if you can't find something that works.  These links will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753914/import-data-from-text-file-and-display-in-datagrid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkS_sxNoiak

Comment: im not sure about the framework,im quite new to this, i use visual studios 13 and then windowsFormApplication, i don't have any samples of code because i don't really know how to start

Comment: That's OK.  Windows Forms (or WinForms) is the framework, and C# is the language that you are using.  If you Google "c# winforms datagridview" you will find dozens of tutorials.  Try walking through one or two of those to get you started - those will be much more thorough than any quick answer that somebody can give you on a forum such as this.  Stack Overflow is better for specific questions about problems with code that you have already written.  I also used PluralSight.com to get me started with coding - they have in-depth video courses for all skill levels.  They have free trials as well.

Comment: ok ill try that, thanks

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952161/c-sharp-saving-a-datagridview-to-file-and-loading Hope this help.
JL